# Addons Software in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I brought Software list of a device using guest.getSoftwareComponents(). 
What about addons ? I can't find Java Softlayer API to get Addon software products.

An operating system provides with its terms of service with link. How can I get the link depends on OSs ? I can't find "ThirdPartyPolicyAssignment" object in SoftwareDescription using java API. 
[image: AddOns]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this objetcMask

```
    String user = "set me";
    String apiKey = "set me";

    long virtualGuestId = 1111;

    ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(user, apiKey);

    Guest.Service service = Guest.service(client, virtualGuestId);
    service.setMask("mask[softwareComponents[softwareLicense[softwareDescription[productItems[thirdPartyPolicyAssignments[policyName]]]]],firewallServiceComponent,frontendNetworkComponents[primaryVersion6IpAddressRecord,ipAddressBindings,primarySubnet[networkVlan[networkVlanFirewall,dedicatedFirewallFlag,primaryRouter[datacenter]]]]]");

    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(service.getObject()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to retrieve the VSI. "
                + e.getMessage());
    }
```

About the Addons from your image this is making reference to the firewall in the device.

there is two types of firewalls: hardware firewall and deidcated firewall.

In order to know if your server has installed a hardware firewall you only have to review if there is any data inside the "firewallServiceComponent" property in case this is empty the server does not have any hardware firewall installed.

For dedicated firewall you have to review the "frontendNetworkComponents" property and verify if this is a dedicated firewall, for that you can use this objectMask `frontendNetworkComponents[primarySubnet[networkVlan[dedicatedFirewallFlag]]]` , in case the  "dedicatedFirewallFlag" is 1 the server belongs to a dedicated Firewall.

regarding to the 3 party link you only can have the policeName using this object mask:

```
softwareComponents[softwareLicense[softwareDescription[productItems[thirdPartyPolicyAssignments[policyName]]]]]
```

Regards